# Appium Inspector don't open on Linux Ubuntu

Tags: linux, appium, appium-desktop

I cannot open Appium inspector on Linux Ubuntu.

In the same folder I have 3 files:
Appium-Inspector-linux-2022.2.1.AppImage /
Appium-Server-GUI-linux-1.22.2.AppImage /
latest-linux.yml

When I open the Appium-Server-GUI-linux-1.22.2.AppImage file, start the server e click on the button to open Appium Ispector, it open a web page.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to fix this, it was necessary:
1: Start Appium Server
I did this, executing Appium-Server-GUI-linux-1.22.2.AppImage file.

2: Start Appium Inspector through of file Appium-Inspector-linux-2022.2.1.AppImage

3: Create the capabilities

After that, the Appium Inspector still don't open throught on Appium Server button, but it make it open and you can use.

Answer (score -1):

Since the release of Appium v1.22 they have changed how the Appium Inspector works. I refer you to their official documentation on GitHub https://github.com/appium/appium-inspector, citing:

> Appium Inspector is released in two formats:
>
> - As a desktop app for macOS, Windows, and Linux. You can get the most
>   recent published version of this app at the Releases section of this
>   repo. Simply grab the appropriate version for your OS and follow
>   standard installation procedures (but see the note below for macOS).
> - As a web application, hosted by Appium Pro. (It's currently a known
>   issue that the web version does not work on Safari). Please make sure
>   to read the note below on CORS as well.

If you like to work the old way, download Appium Desktop v1.21 or below.

Answer (score -1):

1. install latest appium-inspector
2. open appium-inspector and insert "/wd/hub" in Remote Path

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).